# Basic product builder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a very basic product builder. Part of the builder has a basic text editor including some text color presets. As it stands, the presets remove a class that defines the text color and add in their own color class.

Looking at my code, it feels absurdly clunky and inefficient. I'm sure there has to be a better way to achieve what I'm working on, but I'm having a hard time figuring out even a starting point to research on what I would need to do to fix this.

```
$(".black-sel").click(function(){
  $("#prevTex").removeClass (function (index, css) {
    return (css.match (/\btextc-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');});
  $("#prevTex").addClass("textc-black");
});
$(".white-sel").click(function(){
  $("#prevTex").removeClass (function (index, css) {
    return (css.match (/\btextc-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');});
  $("#prevTex").addClass("textc-white");
});
$(".red-sel").click(function(){
  $("#prevTex").removeClass (function (index, css) {
    return (css.match (/\btextc-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');});
  $("#prevTex").addClass("textc-red");
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `removeClass` can take a space seperated string of classes to remove, just store all of the classes in a variable and pass that to clear the existing color.

I would also change it so that your button has a `data-color` attribute to specify the color then you can just have a single event binding, then you color list can be populated from the color selector buttons (thanks Anton Boritskiy) :

JS

```
var colors = ''; 
$(".color-sel")
  .each(function(){ colors +=" textc-" + $(this).data("color"); })
  .click(function(){
      $("#prevTex").removeClass(colors);
      $("#prevTex").addClass("textc-" + $(this).data("color"));
  });
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" class="color-sel" data-color="black" value="Black" />
<input type="button" class="color-sel" data-color="red" value="Red" />
<input type="button" class="color-sel" data-color="white" value="White" />
```

Working Example - http://jsfiddle.net/jvzvL4q7/1/

Comment: `colors` can also be built dynamically from `data-color` attributes.
`var colors = ''; $(".color-sel").each(function(){ colors +=" textc-" + $(this).data("color")});`

Comment: I like your answer much better than mine.

Comment: This is exactly the type of thing I've been looking for. Much appreciated for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Abstract a common function out:

```
var myFunction = function(myClass){
  $("#prevTex").removeClass (function (index, css) {
    return (css.match (/\btextc-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');});
  $("#prevTex").addClass(myClass);
});
```

Then apply it like so:

```
$(".black-sel").click(function(){ myFunction("textc-black"); });
$(".white-sel").click(function(){ myFunction("textc-white"); });
$(".red-sel").click(function(){ myFunction("textc-red"); });
```

Comment: There's been an edit-suggestion by a user without comment privileges to put `$("#prevText")` into a variable as further improvement of this answer. What you want to do with that info is yours to take ;)